# prompt user to intall Google Chrome if not already in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome

I am developing an Angular 6 application using some third party controls with custom coding. Some functionality does not behave as desired on IE. Therefore, we have put a note for the user to use Google Chrome for best experience. This intranet website will have large user base. I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically check whether or not Google Chrome is installed on client's machine. If not, prompt them to install it providing the download and install link.
Please guide

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator You need `.userAgent`

Comment: You can check for current browser but I don't think you can have access to check if an app is installed on a system

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector you can use this package for this

Comment: It's not possible to get the installed applications on a device from the browser. This would be a huge data privacy issue if it was possible... You can use the package Jánosi-Borsos Róbert suggested to get the browser information, however.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your useful input. I am able to detect browser using navigator.userAgent and should be able to provide prompt appropriately.